# Spring Rest ErrorHandling @ControllerAdvice / @Valid

Tags: java, spring, rest, error-handling

I'm having trouble when Using **@ControllerAdvice** and **@Valid** annotations together in a REST controller.

I have a rest controller declared as follows:

```
@Controller
public class RestExample {

    ...

    /**
     * <XmlRequestUser><username>user1</username><password>password</password><name>Name</name><surname>Surname</surname></XmlRequestUser>
     * curl -d "@restAddRequest.xml" -H "Content-Type:text/xml" http://localhost:8080/SpringExamples/servlets/rest/add
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="rest/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String add(@Valid @RequestBody XmlRequestUser xmlUser) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(xmlUser.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(xmlUser.getPassword());
        user.setName(xmlUser.getName());
        user.setSurname(xmlUser.getSurname());

        // add user to the database
        StaticData.users.put(xmlUser.getUsername(), user);
        LOG.info("added user " + xmlUser.getUsername());

        return "added user " + user.getUsername();
    }
}
```

And an ErrorHandler class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RestErrorHandler.class);


    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(final RuntimeException e, WebRequest request) {
        LOG.error(e);

        String bodyOfResponse = e.getMessage();
        return handleExceptionInternal(e, bodyOfResponse, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
    }
}
```

The problem is that, if I add a *"throw new RuntimeException"* within the method **RestExample.add** then the exception is correctly handled by **RestErrorHandler** class.

However when curling a not valid request to the controller the **RestErrorHandler** doesn't catch the exception thrown by the validator and I receive a **400 BadRequest** response. (For not valid request I mean an xml request where Username is not specified)

Note that **XmlRequestUser** class is autogenerated by the plugin **[maven-jaxb2-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/) + [krasa-jaxb-tools](https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools)** (pom.xml):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
            <include>*.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <args>
            <arg>-XJsr303Annotations</arg>
            <arg>-XJsr303Annotations:targetNamespace=http://www.foo.com/bar</arg>
        </args>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.krasa</groupId>
                <artifactId>krasa-jaxb-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${krasa-jaxb-tools.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The generated class has correctly a @NotNull Annotation on Username and Password fields.

My **context.xml** is very easy, containing just a scanner for controllers and enabling mvc:annotation-driven

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.aa.rest" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Does anybody know how to make working @ControllerAdvice and @Valid annotations together in a REST controller?

Thanks in advance.
Antonio

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you need to override the [handleMethodArgumentNotValid()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html#handleMethodArgumentNotValid%28org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException,%20org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,%20org.springframework.http.HttpStatus,%20org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest%29) instead of the `handleException()` method, e.g.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException exception,
            HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status,
            WebRequest request) {

        LOG.error(exception);
        String bodyOfResponse = exception.getMessage();
        return new ResponseEntity(errorMessage, headers, status);
    }
}
```

From the JavaDoc of [MethodArgumentNotValidException](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/MethodArgumentNotValidException.html):

> Exception to be thrown when validation on an argument annotated with @Valid fails.

In other words, a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is thrown when the validation fails. It is handled by the `handleMethodArgumentNotValid()` method provided by the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, that needs to be overridden if you would like a custom implementation.

Comment: @matsev Instead of extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and overriding the handleMethodArgumentNotValid method, couldn't he simply use a @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class) ?

Comment: @StephaneEybert Sure, why not. I chose to extend the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` because it was already extended in the original question. Related: by using the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation (regardless if you extend the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` or use the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation) you get consistent error handling for all controllers.

Comment: I have overriden method handleMethodArgumentNotValid, but that seems to be unused, I checked with debugging by setting breakpoint. Is there any other configuration I need to do beside just overriding the method?

Comment: i override handleMethodArgumentNotValid() in @controllerAdvice but i am not able to handle exception when required parameter not present

Comment: same here have you found a solution @BhartiLadumor? and @shafiul

Comment: I solved the issue with required parameters not present mentioned by @BhartiLadumor removing `@NotNull` lombok annotations from the fields. This way the objects had chance to be instantiated and then be validated.

Answer (score 4):

Better format of return message:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status,
        WebRequest request) {
    BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
    List<FieldErrorVM> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors().stream()
            .map(f -> new FieldErrorVM(f.getObjectName(), f.getField(), f.getCode()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, "Method argument not valid, fieldErrors:" + fieldErrors ,new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. As a slight improvement, you can collect your stream using `toMap` and pass the resulting map with the fields direclty to `handleExceptionInternal` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to this I had another problem on recursive validation.

> The generated classes were missing a **@valid** annotation on the other XmlElements.

The reason for this is related to the fact that I was wrongly using the namespaces:

The plugin is configured to use a particular namespace

```
<arg>-XJsr303Annotations:targetNamespace=http://www.foo.com/bar</arg>
```

So the XSD need to have this as target namespace (e.g.):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/bar"
    xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.com/bar" >

    <xs:complexType name="XmlPassword">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="encryption" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="XmlToken">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="password" type="foo:XmlPassword" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Kind regards
Antonio